# How to save image to another server using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, file-upload

i want to save image and documents to another server than the one laravel is installed:

Server 1 - Laravel
Server 2 - Images and Documents

I don't want to use FTP. How can i achieve same in laravel.

Comment: Welcome to SO ..create api in another server and from main server upload to another server

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you might wanted to create an API on Laravel server 2 and then from laravel server 1 you have to call the server 2 api end point and upload an media/images.

Personally i would never implement something like this.

- Option1: I would go with AWS storage or google cloud storage or similar then your technique.
- Option2: Ideally i would keep image/docs on same server because on server file system doesn't take much resources or CPU. so its always easy to keep it on same server.